# Centralizing authentication in separate IdentityServer app, but using resource owner password flow

Tags: angular, jwt, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-web-app-service

I'm working on two Angular 2 applications with a .NET Core 1.1 REST backend and to be hosted on Azure App Service.  I would like for them to share authentication info so that you don't need to login twice (effectively SSO).  I also want to integrate with 3rd party providers using OAuth/OpenID Connect, but also have the option of creating an account.  And ideally, I would like for both apps to use a native login/password GUI (no redirect to some other service) when not going to the 3rd party providers.

To support all of the above and for easy scaling (not maintaining server-side sessions), I believe I want to use JWT bearer authentication from the SPAs.  IdentityServer4 seems to fit the bill and I could even create a 3rd app to host it so I can share between the two public-facing apps.  The resource owner password flow would allow me to use the native GUI.

Where I'm having trouble is what to do with the 3rd party providers.  If I'm using resource owner flow, the shared IdentityServer4 app wouldn't be reached directly from the browser, so it seems I would need to implement the OAuth/OpenID Connect in both SPAs.  Is the only way to avoid implementing this logic on both SPA apps to use one of the other flows that does the redirects to a shared IdentityServer4 GUI?  In other words, using resource owner password flow, can I still have IdentityServer4 handle the 3rd party authentication somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Resource Owner Flow wont give you SSO because its a RESTful browser-less flow (ie you can do it using any HTTP client). Basically you will not be able to be issued session by IdentityServer4 because of this. Only something like Implicit flow will give you this capability, the reason being that implicit flow can only be done through a browser of sorts which means that IdentityServer4 can issue a session to the browser. Resource Owner should never be considered a flow to use when you want SSO. If you were using Implicit flow all of your issues here would be possible and there is even loads of official IdentityServer4 sample code out there to help you out.

Comment: If both SPA apps are on the same domain and both read/write to the same localStorage location (and thus share a token), wouldn't I effectively have SSO even with resource owner flow?  You could even share localStorage through an iframe across domains (e.g. https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage)

Comment: In my comment above I'm specifically referring to username/password on my site, not any of the 3rd party providers.